# I'm trying to find out the voltage of my TV LEDs as I wish to replace them

Tags: voltage, led-strip

I have a seven LED strip from a 32" Soniq TV. The strip's model number is E340369 and I want to find out its voltage. Could someone please help as I don't have a multimeter to test.

Comment: Harbor freight gives away multimeters almost weekly.

Comment: Use a 300 to 300mA driver CC near 21V

Answer (score 1):

The LED strip is likely to have the LEDs wired in series and be powered by a constant-current supply.

White LEDs have a forward voltage of about 3V, so an estimate for this strip would be 7 LEDs x 3V per LED, or about 21V at some nominal drive current. Since the current isn't known, estimate 20mA as a starting point when testing.

---

MORE:

Could this be it on Alibaba? https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ES-760-2-MA-SON-LED_1600219691244.html

Says 3V/LED, and 1W/LED. So about 21V at 330mA for the strip.

Comment: Ok thanks heaps. You kinda lost me as my knowledge is limited. I've been asked by the seller if it's 3v or 6v? I'm taking it to be 3v. Thanks

Comment: I meant am I correct with it being 3v?

Comment: Can you confirm if the LEDs are connected in parallel or serial? If they're parallel they'll be 3V, in series the strip will be 21V (7 x 3V).

Comment: A comment and request. A reader upvoted this *and* a bunch of my other answers at the same time. While I appreciate the upvotes, please don’t. SE catches those and reverses them.